# R Fill NA with last value for a max of n times

Tags: r, missing-data, fillna

There are multiple ways to fill missing values in R. However, I can't find a solution for filling just the last n NAs.

Available options:

```
na_vector <- c(1, NA, NA, NA, 2, 3, NA, NA)

library(zoo)

na.locf(na_vector)
# Outputs: [1] 1 1 1 1 2 3 3 3

na.locf0(na_vector, maxgap = 2)
# Outputs: [1] 1 NA NA NA  2  3  3  3
```

How I would like it to be:

```
na_vector <- c(1, NA, NA, NA, 2, 3, NA, NA)

fill_na <- function(vector, n){
   ...
}

fill_na(na_vector, n = 1)
# Outputs: [1] 1 1 NA NA  2  3  3  NA

fill_na(na_vector, n = 2)
# Outputs: [1] 1 1 1 NA  2  3  3  3
```

Comment: Your examples don’t match your description of “filling the last n NAs”. The last value for `fill_na(na_vector, n = 1)` is still `NA`. Can you clarify?

Comment: It looks like you actually want to replace the *first* n within each run of `NA`s. Is that right?

Comment: That's right! Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option to get those outputs using `dplyr` and recursion:

```r
na_vector <- c(1, NA, NA, NA, 2, 3, NA, NA)

fill_na <- function(vector, n){
  if (n == 0) {
    vector
  } else {
    fill_na(
      vector = dplyr::coalesce(vector, dplyr::lag(vector)),
      n = n - 1
    )
  }
}

fill_na(na_vector, n = 1)
# [1]  1  1 NA NA  2  3  3 NA

fill_na(na_vector, n = 2)
# [1]  1  1  1 NA  2  3  3  3
```

Answer (score 0):

Number the NA's in each consecutive run of NA's giving `a` and then only fill in those with a number less than or equal to `n`.  This uses only vector operations internally and no iteration or recursion.

```
library(collapse)
library(zoo)

fill_na <- function(x, n) {
  a <- ave(x, groupid(is.na(x)), FUN = seq_along)
  ifelse(a <= n, na.locf0(x), x)
}

fill_na(na_vector, 1)
## [1]  1  1 NA NA  2  3  3 NA
fill_na(na_vector, 2)
## [1]  1  1  1 NA  2  3  3  3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to **impute everything except the last n NA's** based on base R + imputeTS.

```
library(imputeTS)
na_vector <- c(1, NA, NA, NA, 2, 3, NA, NA)

# The function that allows imputing everything except the last n NAs
fill_except_last_n_na <- function(x, n) {
  index <- which(rev(cumsum(rev(as.numeric(is.na(x))))) == n+1)
  x[1:tail(index,1)] <- na_locf(x[1:tail(index,1)])
  return(x)
}

# Call the new function
fill_except_last_n_na(na_vector,2)

## Result
[1]  1  1  1  1  2  3 NA NA
```

When you want to use another imputation option than last observation carried forward, you can just replace the `na_locf` with `na_ma` (moving average), `na_interpolation` (interpolation), `na_kalman` (Kalman Smooting on State Space Models) or other imputation function provided by the **imputeTS** package (see also in the [imputeTS documentation](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2017/RJ-2017-009/index.html) for a list of functions.